# Count the difference in SQL result

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table like this.

```
+-------------+-------+
|    vtype    | isreq |
+-------------+-------+
| Near        |     0 |
| Near        |     1 |
| Far         |     0 |
| Near to far |     0 |
+-------------+-------+
```

I would like to get number that has different `isreq` but the same type. Anyone please?

Comment: You mean you need just the count which satisfy your condition?

Comment: if the type is the same and it has different isreq it will be count 1.

Comment: For the given example, show your expected output.

Comment: this is my query Select count(*) from @table where type = type and isreq != isreq

my expected result is 1

Comment: what if both vtype has same isreq, Then the count should be 0?

Comment: Thanks Pang for the edit :D

Comment: Anyone? Yes: **you**! You're lucky people keep answering these effortless questions for a few reputation points.

Comment: what do you mean effortless?

Comment: Well, you may have spent weeks of effort in this before asking this question, but you don't show it. You only ask others to solve a problem. This *does* show that you never took the effort to read the site help on [how to ask questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for your requirement. Try to test if with more data.

```
select count(*) from
    yourTable a 
        inner join 
    yourTable b
on a.vtype=b.vtype
and a.isreq < b.isreq
group by a.vtype,a.isreq
```

**See fiddle demo here on MySQL**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b51bf8/11

Comment: If it works for you, please accept the answer by clicking on the `tick` symbol on left of the answer so it could be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I needed.

```
DECLARE @table as table(vtype varchar(15),isreq varchar(5))

insert into @table values ('Near','0')
insert into @table values ('Near','1')
insert into @table values ('Far','0')
insert into @table values ('Near to Far','0')

SELECT count(*) FROM @table WHERE vtype = vtype and isreq = isreq 
SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(*)-1) AS result FROM @table WHERE vtype = vtype and isreq = isreq GROUP BY vtype HAVING (COUNT(*)-1)>0
```